# Trying to align radio buttons with input fields horizontally

Tags: drop-down-menu, radio-button

I'm trying to align four radio buttons horizontally to the right of a dropdown select field.  The dropdown field is the primary input and the radio buttons give the users four separate options to select for the field they select from the dropdown.

The problem I'm having is getting the radio buttons to line up horizontally to the right of the dropdown select field.  I've been tweaking the html and playing around with some css attributes but I haven't gotten the radios to line up horizontally to the right of the select field.

I'm hoping to do this with only html and css, but will resort to javascript if this is too hard with these tools.

Here's what I have right now...

```css
.pcode select {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 80px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<p>P-Codes (select all that apply)</p>

    <div class="pcode">
            <select id="pcode1">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="51xx">51XX</option>
            <option value="52xx">52XX</option>
            <option value="53xx">53XX</option>
            <option value="55xx">55XX</option>
            <option value="56xx">55XX</option>
            <option value="57xx">57XX</option>
            <option value="58xx">58XX</option>
            <option value="6203">6203</option>
        </select>
    </div> 

    <input type="radio" name="ptype1" value="d">D
    <input type="radio" name="ptype1" value="p">P
    <input type="radio" name="ptype1" value="q">Q
    <input type="radio" name="ptype1" value="s">S
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it....

```css
  .pcode select {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 80px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  float left;
  display: inline-block;
```

```html
<div class="pcode">
  <select id="pcode1">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="51xx">51XX</option>
            <option value="52xx">52XX</option>
            <option value="53xx">53XX</option>
            <option value="55xx">55XX</option>
            <option value="56xx">56XX</option>
            <option value="57xx">57XX</option>
            <option value="58xx">58XX</option>
            <option value="6203">6203</option>
  </select>
  <input type="radio" name="ptype1" value="d">D
  <input type="radio" name="ptype1" value="p">P
  <input type="radio" name="ptype1" value="q">Q
  <input type="radio" name="ptype1" value="s">S
</div>

<div class="pcode">
  <select id="pcode2">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="51xx">51XX</option>
            <option value="52xx">52XX</option>
            <option value="53xx">53XX</option>
            <option value="55xx">55XX</option>
            <option value="56xx">56XX</option>
            <option value="57xx">57XX</option>
            <option value="58xx">58XX</option>
            <option value="6203">6203</option>
  </select>
  <input type="radio" name="ptype2" value="d">D
  <input type="radio" name="ptype2" value="p">P
  <input type="radio" name="ptype2" value="q">Q
  <input type="radio" name="ptype2" value="s">S
</div>
```